# Why there are two program file folders in 64 bit windows?

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I want to know why there are two folders while we need one.
Eg. Program Files and Program Files(x86)

Answer (score 0):

64bit programs don't run on a 32bit system.

Similar as there is a System32 and Syswow64, there is a program files and program files (x86)

A 64-bit program will by default get installed to Program Files and their shared DLL's will be placed in System32, where a x86 (or 32bit) program will be installed to Program Files (x86) and their shared dll's to Syswow64.

There is no real need for this other than, you can keep programs apart and run a 32-bit and 64-bit version next to eachother.

Comment: For those who think I made a typo up here, I haven't. System32 is for 64-bit programs, and SYSWOW64 is for 32-bit programs. Google it up if you got curious.

Answer (score 0):

Programfiles is where your 64 bits programs are installed

ProgramFiles(x86) is where your 32 bits programs are installed